# using memoize in groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, tdd, memoization, spock

I am currently practicing test driven development in groovy using spock.
I have 1 set of tests where 3 different implementations doing the same thing: iterative, recursive, and memoized.
so I have created an abstract class to hold the tests, and then created 3 different files to return the concrete class implementation to run the tests. I have iterative and recursive working, but I am having issues with memoize()

```
import spock.lang.Specification
abstract class FibonacciTest extends Specification {
    private calculator
    abstract def getCalculator()
    def setup() {
        calculator = getCalculator()
    }
    def "test canary"() {
        expect:
        true
    }
    // more tests
}

class RecursiveFibonacciTest extends FibonacciTest {
    def getCalculator() {
        new RecursiveCalculator()
    }
}

class IterativeFibonacciTest extends FibonacciTest {
    def getCalculator() {
        new IterativeCalculator()
    }
}

class MemoizeFibonacciTest extends FibonacciTest {
    def getCalculator() {
        new MemoizeCalculator()
    }
}

class RecursiveCalculator {
    def getFibonacci(position) {
        if (position < 2) {
            1
        }
        else {
            getFibonacci(position - 1) + getFibonacci(position - 2)
        }
    }
}

class IterativeCalculator {
    def getFibonacci(position) {
        if (position < 2) {
            1
        }
        else {
            def value = 1
            def previousValue = 1
            for (i in 2..position) {
                def temporaryValue = previousValue
                previousValue = value
                value = temporaryValue + previousValue
            }
        value
        }
    }
}
```

So I've got the iterative and recursive working, but having problems getting the memoize to work.. I think it should work with this, but its not.. anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
class MemoizeCalculator {
    def getFibonacci = { position ->
        if (position < 2)
            1
        else
            getFibonacci.call(position - 1) + getFibonacci.call(position - 2)
    }.memoize()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the `getFibonacci` variable from the same statement that declares it. Either change `getFibonacci.call` to `call`, or declare the variable (`def getFibonacci`) before assigning it (`getFibonacci = ...`).

Comment: I tried def getFibonacci, then set getFibonacci = { position -> ... }.memoize() 
kind of what all the documents stated, but i keep getting unexpected and other errors. i suppose i'm just not getting it.. can you be a slight more explicit? i dont understand the changing getFibonacci.call to call either. :/ sorry, im just learning to program..

Comment: Just do exactly what I said. Either replace all occurrences of `getFibonacci.call` with `call` (inside the closure you don't need to qualify its own methods), or replace `def getFibonacci = { ... }` with `def getFibonacci; getFibonacci = { ... }`. Both solutions work fine for me. PS: If you hit any errors, show them as part of your question (exact output, stack trace, etc.).

Comment: i opted to try the replacing `getFibonacci.call` with `call` , but got the following error.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.Memoize$MemoizeFunction.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]
Possible solutions: call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), findAll(), equals(java.lang.Object)
 at FibonacciTest.test first number in sequence is 1(FibonacciTest.groovy:22)

Comment: How are you invoking the method? `calculator.getFibonacci.call(5)` works for me, but `calculator.getFibonacci(5)` gives the error you show. Not sure if this is expected or a Groovy bug. I also discovered that as of Groovy 2.1.1, it's not strictly necessary to omit the `fibonacci.` inside the closure. From what I remember, it used to be necessary in earlier Groovy versions.

Comment: its being invoked by `calculator.getFibonacci(5)`, and indeed, when i invoke the method by `calculator.getFibonacci.call(5)` it works.. however, it then breaks my iterative and recursive tests. i will try your other option, perhaps

Comment: You will have to adapt the other option a bit for use within a class (e.g. by enclosing the assignment with `{ ... }`), and I'm not sure if it will help. I recommend to ask on the Groovy mailing list why omitting `.call` doesn't work in this case, and whether that's a bug.